# How to fix " module javafx.graphics does not "opens com.sun.javafx.text" to unnamed module" problem in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, java-12

I am using

```
jdk12,javafx12
```

and eclipse ide. When I run my code it should create a pane a textfield and some buttons. It just creates the pane and then I get an error

I tried using

```
jdk11
```

I got the same error

I wrote these to

```
VM
```

arguments:

```
--module-path /home/beyza/openjfx-12.0.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk- 
12.0.1/lib
--add-modules javafx.controls
--add-modules javafx.base
--add-modules javafx.graphics
--add-modules javafx.fxml
--add-modules javafx.media
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom.transform=ALL- 
UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL- 
UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.paint=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.effect=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.geom=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text=ALL-UNNAMED
```

[Here is my main class](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSpmr8xWhy/)

I got this error

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable 
    to make private int 
    com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getLineIndex(float) 
    accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens 
    com.sun.javafx.text" to unnamed module
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any of those `--add-exports` or `--add-opens`, since you are including the JavaFX modules, unless you are using private API (we don't see your FXML controllers), which is obviously discouraged. If you still need to use it, post the code that uses it.

Comment: You should include the full stack trace of the exception. The message indicates that someone is attempting to access the method `private int  com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getLineIndex(float)` via Reflection with access override. Application code should not do that.

Comment: Add `--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text=ALL-UNNAMED` to your options. Or don't do whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is `--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text=ALL-UNNAMED` to VM options.

But anyone can avoid those VM options if write a simple launcher class like this:

```
public class AppLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourAppMainClassNameHere.main(args);
    }
}
```

And run the app through this.

Comment: I spent 20 minutes adding every package to exports, this solved it in instant. Thanks  Gabor.